# Swift detailCalloutAccessoryView change style not working

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using MKAnnotationView to show a custom view when a user taps a pin on the map. The custom view displays fine and I'm using `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` to show it.

I'm using the `detailCalloutAccessoryView` as I need to have the tableView inside the `detailCalloutAccessoryView`. The problem I'm having is that I can't change the backgroundColor, remove the padding or remove the Shadow opacity of the detailAccessoryView.

I've also tried to solve this by creating a customView and changing the `CanShowCallout` to false and just adding it to the view using `view.addSubView(customView)` which looks exactly as the design however the tableView doesn't scroll - I guess that's because it's just a view.

How can I change the detailAccessoryView?

```
view.detailCalloutAccessoryView?.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
view.detailCalloutAccessoryView?.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Red") ?? red
view.detailCalloutAccessoryView?.superview?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
```

Things I've also tried:

```
        detailCalloutAccessoryView?.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
    detailCalloutAccessoryView?.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10)
    
    detailCalloutAccessoryView?.superview?.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
    detailCalloutAccessoryView?.superview?.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10)
    
    let constraints = [
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: detailCalloutAccessoryView, attribute: .topMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: detailCalloutAccessoryView.superview, attribute: .bottomMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: detailCalloutAccessoryView.superview, attribute: .leftMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: detailCalloutAccessoryView.superview, attribute: .rightMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
    ]

    detailCalloutAccessoryView?.addConstraints(constraints)
```

Comment: Did manage to fix this?

Comment: @Asteroid - No, we ended up redesigning the callout view.

Comment: But how do you redesign it completely? When I add my custom view, I cannot get rid of the containing view and the location arrow!